# django-admin bad interpreter: Permission Denied

Tags: python, linux, django, suse

I'm trying to use django on a Suse server to use it in production with apache and mod_python but I'm finding some problems.

I have installed python 2.7.9 (the default version was 2.6.4) and django 1.7. I had some problem with the installation but they are now solved.

My current problem is that when I try to execute django-admin I get this error:

-bash: /usr/local/bin/django-admin: .: bad interpreter: Permission denied

I have searched through the web but I have not found a solution. I have tried to make the file executable: sudo chmod +x django-admin  and the problem remains equal.

Any idea? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I have no problem executing python. It works typing "python" as well as "python2.7". The problem is when I try to execute django-admin and this problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the python interpreter is what you don't have permission for. Do you have permission to run python?

Comment: I have no problem executing python. It works typing "python" as well as "python2.7"

Answer (score 0):

had you try add your user to the group with persmission for execute python?
you can look the file /etc/passwd . In these file you can describe each permission.

Comment: I have no problem executing python. It works typing "python" as well as "python2.7"